# Etiquette: Review request for a tag that I think should be removed

Tags: discussion, support

I have a queued review request for the [count](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/count) tag. At the time of writing, this tag has 3 questions -- [one with an accepted answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/93/is-there-a-way-to-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-file), [one that's marked as a duplicate of the former](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2502/how-can-i-count-instances-of-character-x), and [one for which the tag doesn't really seem appropriate](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/506/how-can-i-easily-get-the-length-of-a-piece-of-text).

Frankly, I think there is not much else to ask related to count.

The tag already exists, and I've got this pending review. The suggested edit is a good description of what that tag covers, but since I believe there's really only one unique question that fits the category, I think the tag should ultimately be removed.

Do I reject the edit? Do I approve it, but later petition for the tag to be removed?

Comment: In the context of Vi/Vim, I would have thought "count" would refer to the numeric argument of a command in normal mode (e.g. "3" in "c3w"), **not** to the "number of occurrences of something in a document." So I don't think I agree that the suggested edit is a good description of what the tag covers, and moreover I think this shows how poorly named the tag is.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. Maybe this tag should be renamed "counting".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as the tag exists, adding a description (a [tag wiki](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), or at least an [excerpt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts)) is a good thing. Please accept the edit if the description of the tag is appropriate.

If you think the tag should not exist, remove it from the few questions that have it and reject the tag wiki with a custom message explaining why.

This is a budding site, so “there is only one question” is not a good argument against a tag. Every tag has to start somewhere. [count](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/count) sounds reasonably discoverable to me as a description of a type of task.