# Another review request for the [count] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [count](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/count) tag was [discussed a couple of years ago](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/etiquette-review-request-for-a-tag-that-i-think-should-be-removed), but I think we need to take another look at it.

At the time, it seems to have been decided (based on the three existing questions) that the tag should continue to be used for "tasks involved counting things", and the tag description was updated accordingly.

However, Kyle Strand suggested that, in the context of Vim, the word "count" already has a meaning, (See `:help count`) and that it would make more sense to use the tag for this feature.

I agree with this, and apparently so do at least some of our users. As of right now, 3 of the 11 tagged questions relate to this usage (with another that I was about to tag before discovering this issue). 7 are clearly related to the other use and 1 isn't quite either.

My questions:

1. Does anyone else agree with Kyle and I that the [count](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/count) tag should be used for vim's `count` feature?
2. Should we simply remove the tag from some of the questions, or should we split it into two tags? (There's also the option of continuing to use the tag for both different meanings, but that doesn't seem like a good solution to me.)
3. If the latter, what should the two tags be called in order to minimise confusion? [count](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/count) and [counting](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counting)? [count](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/count) and [counting-things](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counting-things)? [count](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/count) and [vim-count](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-count)?

Comment: Personally, I think tags such as this add very little value. Can you be an expert in "counting"? Can you be especially interested in "counting"? Probably not.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker So maybe then we should delete the tag entirely?

Comment: Although I'd argue there is value in having all questions concerning Vim's `count` easily searchable.

Comment: @Rich in that case somebody will have to police the tag and make sure it doesn't get cluttered with other uses of count.

Comment: @muru I see your point, but I don't think that would be an onerous task, considering the number of questions affected. I think spending 5 mins every two years would probably cover it, and I'd be happy to commit that amount of time myself so long as no-one objects to me doing so.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** I've now done this.

This continues to bug me.

I'm presuming that the lack of response here suggests that the rest of the community doesn't really care about this either way, so unless this answer gets a lot of downvotes in the next few days I'm going to go ahead and move all counting things questions to a new [counting](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counting) tag and edit the [count](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/count) tag to apply to Vim's `count`.

Comment: `the rest of the community doesn't really care about this either way` I can't speak for everyone, but that would certainly be my position :-) Feel free to retag, if you want.